# How to convert a table containing values and frequency to a single list in RStudio?

Tags: r

I have a table with NDVI in column one, Frequency in column two, and timePeriod in column three. The following is the beginning of the list:

[image]

The following is the full .csv:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G3SLWJx6upMELMSrjeS6mny9OMLBkP3x/view?usp=sharing

I would like to change this table so that it has two columns where one is timePeriod and the other is NDVI, where the number of duplicate NDVI rows is equal to the frequency.  Here is an Excel representation:

[image]

Comment: You can use `new_data <- tidyr::uncount(data2004, Frequency)`

Comment: @RonakShah Will this new resultant indexing affect ggplot graphing? https://imgur.com/a/gZZZL3g